# Vue.js passing store data as prop causes mutation warnings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm passing store data (Vuex) as a property of `component` but it's giving me mutation errors even though I'm not changing the data.

Edit: Codepen illustrating error: https://codesandbox.io/s/v8onvz427l

Input

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="input" />
        <div style="padding-top: 5px">
            <button @click="create" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Create</button>
        </div>
        {{ example }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import store from "@/store"

    export default {
        props: {
            "example": {

            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                store
            }
        },
        methods: {
            create() {
                store.commit("general_set_creation_name", {name: this.$refs.input.value})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Modal.vue

```
<template src="./Modal.html"></template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery'

    import store from '@/store'

    export default {
        props: {
            "id": String,
            "height": {
                type: String,
                default: "auto"
            },
            "width": {
                type: String,
                default: "40vw"
            },
            "position": {
                type: String,
                default: "absolute"
            },
            "component": {
                default: null    
            },
            "global": {
                default: true
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                store: store
            }
        },
        computed: {
            body () {
                return store.state.General.modal.body
            },
            props () {
                return store.state.General.modal.props
            },
            title () {
                return store.state.General.modal.title
            },
        },
        methods: {
            close_modal (event) {
                if (event.target === event.currentTarget) {
                    this.$refs.main.style.display = "none"
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss" src="./Modal.scss"></style>
```

Modal.html

```
<div 
    :id="id"
    class="main" 
    ref="main" 
    @click="close_modal"
>
    <div ref="content" class="content" :style="{minHeight: height, minWidth: width, position}">
        <div ref="title" class="title" v-if="title">
            {{ title }}
        </div>
        <hr v-if="title" />
        <div ref="body" class="body">
            <slot></slot>
            <component v-if="global" :is="body" v-bind="props"></component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changing store data with this line in a third component:

```
store.commit("general_set_modal", {body: Input, title: "New "+page, props: {example: "example text 2"})
```

Comment: What commit causes the warning and where are your `mutations`?

Comment: @HMR I've actually got a codepen. https://codesandbox.io/s/v8onvz427l If you hit the `test` button, it'll appear in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure you should not put a vue component on the state. If you are supposed to do that then I don't think the creators of vuex understand how an event store works.

In the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vues-reactivity-rules) it also says you need to initialize your state with values and you don't do that.

Your sandbox works fine when removing the vue component from the state (state should contain data but vue components are objects with both data and behavior).

index.js in store:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    modal: {
      body: {},
      title: "",//det it to something
      props: {}
    },
    creationName: null
  },

  mutations: {
    general_set_creation_name(state, payload) {
      state.creationName = payload.name;
    },
    general_set_modal(state, payload) {
      state.modal.title = payload.title;
      state.modal.props = payload.props;
      console.log("we are fine here");
    }
  },
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert it from my React project, where I pass components. The reason I'm passing the component in the state is because I want to use a global Modal where I am able to substitute components in and out to display different things.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, changing the way I import the class removes the warning

```
const test = () => import('./Test')
```

Details:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/getting-vuex-mutation-error-when-im-only-reading-the-data/27655/11